# Temporal kernel filtering on video frames coming in a loop

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, video, scipy

I have a video which I read in a loop frame by frame. For every frame, I want to do temporal kernel filtering, the coefficients of which come from the input variable model (a dictionary). The temporal kernel is an array that has size of 15. So, basically, for every frame we apply this function. The variables scale, clip_size are constants. Firstly I add borders across the obtained frame. Then I start a buffer of size (15,240,320) where (240,320) is the clip size. Variable `bindex` is used to write the buffer. The buffer variable will store only last 15 modified frames, hence `bindex` needs to be updated at every function iteration. Variable `sindex` is used to traverse through the buffer and apply the buffer, hence it has to be returned too.  Since the `input_frames` are coming from a video in a loop, I had to make some variables be both inputs and outputs. Is there a way to speed this up? Any better way to do this?

```
def filtered_output(input_frame,model, Buffer,bindex,sindex,scale,clip_size):
    # padding is required
    top=model['item'][0]
    bot=model['item1'].shape[1]-top-1
    left=model['item'][1]
    right=model['item1'].shape[0]-left-1
    # NewDepth = 15
    # clip_size is [240,320]
    # In the external loop, bindex = 0, sindex =0 in the beginning
    # We now create a copy of our current frame, with appropriate padding
    frame2= cv2.copyMakeBorder(input_frame,top,bot,left,right,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=0.5)
    Buffer[bindex] = scipy.signal.convolve2d(frame2, model['item1'], boundary='symm', mode='valid')
    sindex = (bindex+1) % NewDepth # point to oldest image in the buffer
    temp=np.zeros(tuple(clip_size),dtype=float)
    temp = model['TempKern'][0]*Buffer[sindex]

    sindex = (sindex+1) % NewDepth
    for j in range(1, NewDepth) :  # iterate from oldest to newest frame
        temp = temp + model['TempKern'][j]*Buffer[sindex]
        sindex = (sindex+1) % NewDepth
    bindex = (bindex+1) % NewDepth
    temp=np.nan_to_num(temp)
    output_frame = ApplyCubicSpline(model['CubicSplineCoeffs'],temp)*scale
    return output_frame, Buffer,bindex,sindex
```

My question is whether we can make this function faster somehow (not that it is slow)? If yes, how? Is it the best practice to use `bindex`, `sindex` as both inputs and outputs to the function? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger : I tried to explain my concerns. I am not concerned whether the output is correct or not. I am mostly concerned with the ways to make it run faster and whether there are better ways or not?

Comment: It's impossible for us to help you unless you give us much more information. The first step in speeding up this kind of code would be to run a profiler on it to see where the time is being spent, but we can't do that because we can't run your code and we don't have any data to run it on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but I focused on that loop:

```
for j in range(1, NewDepth) :  # iterate from oldest to newest frame
    temp = temp + model['TempKern'][j]*Buffer[sindex]
    sindex = (sindex+1) % NewDepth
```

To speed this up you could:

- create a variable to avoid accessing `model['TempKern']` (dict access)
- use in-place adition for `temp`

improved:

```
tk = model['TempKern']
for j in range(1, NewDepth) :  # iterate from oldest to newest frame
    temp += tk[j]*Buffer[sindex]
    sindex = (sindex+1) % NewDepth
```

Aside: outside the loop you do:

```
temp=np.zeros(tuple(clip_size),dtype=float)
temp = model['TempKern'][0]*Buffer[sindex]
```

so you can remove the first line, as it has no effect, `temp` is overwritten at the next line.

Comment: I had doubts about avoiding dictionary access. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Aside from stylistic issues (inconsistent use of whitespace, naming...), your biggest mistake is to not take advantage of `numpy` features whereas you seems to be using `ndarray`s.

But first some miscellaneous comments:

- You can use unpacking to simplify computation of the padding. I also don't know if `model['item']` and `model['item1']` get updated but you may be able to cache the computation so you don't have to perform it at each frame.
- You override `temp` right after it's creation; better remove the `np.zeros` line.
- `sindex` is overriden before being used by `sindex = (bindex+1) % NewDepth` so there is no need of it as a parameter. Thus it should be unnecessary as a return value as well.
- Instead of treating `Buffer` like a circular buffer where you manage an explicit index, it should be better to treat it like a FIFO queue and drop older result when adding a new one. The advantage being that you know in advance that the last entry will always be `Buffer[-1]`. This drops the need for `bindex` as a parameter and a return value.

Now let's use `numpy` to do that:

- Dropping an old entry and appending a new one can be done using: `np.vstack(Buffer[1:], whatever)`.
- The `for` loop can be handled entirely in `numpy`: `model['TempKern'] * Buffer` can take care of all the multiplcations and then you just need to `np.sum` every rows. This assumes that `model['TempKern']` is a `numpy` array.

Revised  code could look like:

```
def filtered_output(input_frame, model,  buffer, scale, clip_size): 
    # padding is required 
    top, left = model['item'] 
    width, height = model['item1'].shape
    bottom = height - top - 1
    right = width - left - 1 
    # Create a copy of our current frame, with appropriate padding 
    frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(input_frame, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0.5) 
    convolved_frame = scipy.signal.convolve2d(frame, model['item1'], boundary='symm', mode='valid') 
    buffer = np.vstack((buffer[1:], convolved_frame))
    # Apply kernel
    temp = np.sum(model['TempKern'] * buffer, axis=0)
    temp = np.nan_to_num(temp) 
    output_frame = ApplyCubicSpline(model['CubicSplineCoeffs'], temp) * scale 
    return output_frame, buffer
```

But you should use better names as `temp` or `item` does not convey much meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is indeed helpful. I wasn't aware of numpy vstack function. Will making buffer a global variable be helpful? Like I dont have to return buffer then, I believe. I would prefer that the function just return the output_frame, because I am planning to use moviepy's fl_image function.

Comment: @GKS I don't know, there is not enough context to answer. I'd say no nonetheless since global variable are often a code smell. Maybe a class? Maybe post a followup question with a bunch more code.

Comment: Here is the follow up question : - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152771/utilizing-moviepys-fl-image-function-efficiently-to-modify-an-incoming-video