# Utilizing Moviepy's fl_image function efficiently to modify an incoming video

Tags: python, opencv

This is a followup question from [this question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152542/temporal-kernel-filtering-on-video-frames-coming-in-a-loop). I used the suggested function provided by an answer in my current code. 'model' is a dictionary loaded from the pickle file. 'loadpickle' and findScale are helper functions. So, I load the model, and other variables and read the moviepy frame by frame. The moviepy's fl_image function is used to convert every frame through a rolling buffer. The buffer has to be updated in the 'filtered_output' function itself. Now, I have an impression that the function supplied to fl_image can take only one input (i.e. the frame) and can return only one output (i.e. the output frame). Hence I had to make 'buffer' global. Also, I have been assuming that constants like scale and clip_size do not need to be included in the function definition of the 'filtered_output' function, and also it is necessary for fl_image function.

```
path=os.getcwd()
model=loadpickle('file.pkl')
scale=findScale(model)
clip_size=(240L,320L,3L)
Scaling=1.5
Offset=0
clip=moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip('input.mp4',audio=False) #Greyscale Video - all 3 channels are the same in the frames
bufshape=15,clip_size[0],clip_size[1]
buffer=np.zeros(BufShape, dtype=float)
modified_clip = clip.fl_image(filtered_output)
print type(modified_clip)
modified_clip.write_videofile(os.path.join(path,'output.mp4'))

def filtered_output(image):
    global buffer
    finalOut=np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=float)
    scaled_frame=Scaling*(image[:,:,0]/ 255.)+Offset
    # padding is required 
    top, left = model['item'] 
    width, height = model['item1'].shape
    bottom = height - top - 1
    right = width - left - 1 
    # Create a copy of our current frame, with appropriate padding 
    frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(scaled_frame, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0.5) 
    convolved_frame = scipy.signal.convolve2d(frame, model['item1'], boundary='symm', mode='valid') 
    buffer = np.vstack((buffer[1:], convolved_frame))
    # Apply kernel
    temp = np.sum(model['TempKern'] * buffer, axis=0)
    temp = np.nan_to_num(temp) 
    output_frame = ApplyCubicSpline(model['CubicSplineCoeffs'], temp) * scale 
    for i in range(len(finalOut.shape)):
       finalOut[:,:,i]=output_frame # copying frames to make it 3 channels again
    return finalOut
```

So, from this code review I wish to know, whether my assumptions are right. If not, then how do I make this moviepy fl_image work?

Comment: Output2 was output_frame only. Sorry for the confusion. FinalOut is initialized with zeros. Its essentially output_frame copied to make 3 color channels for greyscale image. Fixed the code